# How to anonymously access a firestore document using a password

Tags: firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm building a web app with firebase that can't have an authentication system but still needs to access sensitive data in a firestore document after being given a password. I was thinking about making the password the name of the document, but then I realized this is not secure because someone could query all the documents in the database.

Is there a way to use firebase rules or some other workaround such that the only way to read a document is to have a certain code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable querying for a collection by simply denying `list` access and allowing only `get` access:

```
match /collection/{id} {
  allow get;
}
```

In this way, the user must know the ID of the document in order to get it.  It will only work for the one document that they've been given the ID of.

Otherwise, there is no way to provide a password as part of a query, because that's not actually very secure at all.